# Solving $3y + 2y^2 = -e^{-x} - e^x + c$ for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, roots, quadratics

So, I am failing to understand some potentially simple algebra here. I have a separable equation:$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{e^{-x} - e^x}{3+4y},$$

and after the easy integration I get$$3y + 2y^2 = -e^{-x} - e^x + c .$$

Now, how do I solve for $y$? The book has a fairly long answer involving a square root... It could come down to, I did the separable/integration part incorrectly *or I've lost my mind* but I'm kind of shaking my head over my lack of algebra skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quadratic equation for $y$, so you can feed it to the quadratic formula.  The result is $$y=\frac {-3 \pm \sqrt{9-4\cdot 2(c-e^{-x}-e^x)}}{4\cdot 2}$$

Comment: So important, yet I fill my head with other things!

Comment: The $a$ term is $2$ right? Shouldn't it be $$y=\displaystyle\frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{9-4(2)(c-e^{-x}-e^{x})}}{4(2)}$$?

Comment: @JosephSkelton:  correct.  fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The equation

$$2y^2+3y  +e^{-x} + e^x - c=0$$

is a quadratic in terms of $y$, right?

So, use Bhaskara's formula *(also called Quadratic Equation)* to solve for $y$.